# sort array in php on any key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array in php :

```
$myarray[$index]['height']
$myarray[$index]['weight']
$myarray[$index]['age']
```

which is the best function to sort by any of the key 'height', 'weight' or 'age'?

An an example, if I have in input

```
$myarray[0]['height'] = 175;
$myarray[0]['weight'] = 68;
$myarray[0]['age'] = 44;

$myarray[1]['height'] = 166;
$myarray[1]['weight'] = 82;
$myarray[1]['age'] = 56;

$myarray[2]['height'] = 188;
$myarray[2]['weight'] = 82;
$myarray[2]['age'] = 35;
```

and I want to sort by age, I obtain

```
$myarray[0]['height'] = 188;
$myarray[0]['weight'] = 82;
$myarray[0]['age'] = 35;

$myarray[1]['height'] = 175;
$myarray[1]['weight'] = 68;
$myarray[1]['age'] = 44;

$myarray[2]['height'] = 166;
$myarray[2]['weight'] = 82;
$myarray[2]['age'] = 56;
```

Comment: [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) passing the column you want to sort on to the callback

Answer (score 1):

There's a great example on the [`usort` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for custom sorting multidimensional arrays.

[Here's a fiddle.](https://3v4l.org/686Gn)

```
<?php
$myarray[0]['height'] = 175;
$myarray[0]['weight'] = 68;
$myarray[0]['age'] = 44;

$myarray[1]['height'] = 166;
$myarray[1]['weight'] = 82;
$myarray[1]['age'] = 56;

$myarray[2]['height'] = 188;
$myarray[2]['weight'] = 82;
$myarray[2]['age'] = 35;

function build_sorter($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}

usort($myarray, build_sorter('age'));

print_r($myarray);
```

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [height] => 188
>             [weight] => 82
>             [age] => 35
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [height] => 175
>             [weight] => 68
>             [age] => 44
>         )
>
>     [2] => Array
>         (
>             [height] => 166
>             [weight] => 82
>             [age] => 56
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Comment: thanks, but is strnatcmp is the right function for comparing numbers?

Comment: It works for me, but of course you can modify/substitute it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you need is to sort an array by column. The following code will do the trick:

```
function sortByColumn(&$array, $column, $order = SORT_ASC)
{
    array_multisort(
        array_column($array, $column),
        $order,
        $array
    );
}
```

This approach is using [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) and [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) functions.

Also this way you can specify the order (SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC).

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/418d8e9cb92d3d40dcec8dcfebed0550df4924aa).